# Recommendation for Free Lazy Loading Extensions Magento 2

Tags: magento2, extensions, optimization, lazyload

I'm looking for a recommendation for free lazy loading extension that is likely works for Magento 2.2.9 with infortis ultimo theme.

here are some list i found:

> -welt MAGENTO 2 LAZY LOAD PRODUCTS AND IMAGES.
>
> -bss Magento 2 Lazy Load
>
> -magezon Magento 2 Lazy Load Extension
>
> -Magento 2 Image Lazy Load Extension

have anyone try any of them, and recommended or not recommended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to install them one by one and see which extension is working better for your store.
there is no point to ask for recommendation, every store is unique, works different, and have specific design issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below Extension for Lazy loading

- https://www.magezon.com/magento-2-lazy-load.html